# ℩-descriptor and the axiom of choice?

Tags: logic, soft-question, axiom-of-choice

I've recently finished Nederpelt and Geuvers *Type Theory and Formal Proof*, and I remember somewhere in the book the authors mentioned that their $\iota$-descriptors  (which are used to refer to the unique members that satisfy some predicates once it's proven) are related to Hilbert's $\varepsilon$-operators, and that they are both weaker than the Axiom of Choice. I believe they stopped at that point and didn't say anything about it ever after.

I didn't give much thoughts to it at the time, but now I'm interested to learn what they meant by that the description operator is weaker than the Axiom of Choice.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm going to be sloppy with details here for clarity - in particular, I'm not going to pay attention to exactly how type theory and set theory are interacting. But I don't think this is an issue.*

If I understand things correctly, your recollection is off (or the text states things incorrectly) when it comes to the axiom of choice: $\iota$ is unrelated to choice, while $\epsilon$ is actually *stronger* than choice. (Of course, $\epsilon$ and $\iota$ *are* related to each other.)

I don't have the book at hand, but I believe $\iota$ behaves roughly as: if there is a unique $a$ such that $\varphi(a)$ holds, then $\iota\varphi(x)$ denotes that $a$, and otherwise $\iota\varphi(x)$ is undefined. This is **not** related to the axiom of choice, roughly because given $\varphi$ we can tell what $\iota\varphi$ should be in a non-arbitrary way. A bit technically, we can add the $\iota$-operation (in an appropriate way) to ZF without producing any new theorems of set theory.

By contrast, Hilbert's $\epsilon$-operator does *not* require uniqueness: $\epsilon\varphi(x)$ always denotes an object satisfying $\varphi$ if such an object exists, and is otherwise undefined. Note the fundamental difference between $\epsilon$ and $\iota$: $\epsilon$ has to *make nontrivial decisions* - namely, whenever we feed it a formula with more than one solution - while $\iota$ doesn't.

Put another way, $\epsilon$ has to make choices, indeed lots of choices, and that's where the connection with the axiom of choice comes from. If we add the $\epsilon$-operator to ZF in a reasonable way, we get full choice back since, given a family $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of nonempty sets, a choice function is given by $i\mapsto \iota (x\in A_i)$. In fact, $\epsilon$ gives us a *strengthening* of the axiom of choice, namely [**global choice**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_global_choice): it provides a uniform way to pick an element from a nonempty set.

Comment: The authors said that Hilbert showed the choice operators can be eliminated and are thus redundant (not sure in the context of what). Maybe there were certain restrictions/rules on what objects $\epsilon$ can reference? But what you are saying is more or less what I thought and that's why it confuses me.

Comment: @SpooFwen Can you give me a citation for where the authors say that?

Comment: page 276 in their book

Comment: I thought Hilbert's $\epsilon$ was defined when $\varphi$ is empty, it is just defined to be any arbitrary object, forcing $\varphi(\epsilon \varphi) = \bot$ when $\varphi$ is empty?

Comment: With eliminating the choice operators, the authors might have referred to this:

If $T$ is a theory in the language $\mathcal L$ using choice operators, then there is a theory $T'$ in an extended language $\mathcal L'\supseteq\mathcal L$ without making use of the choice operators, such that $T$ and $T'$ have exactly the same models. 
(Just introduce new function symbols. If I remember correctly, they are called Skolem-functions.)
Since introducing the choice operators does not change the expressive power of the logic they can be considered redundant.

Comment: @DanielV I've seen both versions - which you choose doesn't make a significant difference, of course (at least not in this context).